# Does Lambda run multiple containers when it says 1000 concurrent execution?

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-lambda

When the number of concurrent execution of one lambda increases, does that mean that the Lambda services starts a new container for each concurrent execution behind the scenes, and then that would suffer from Cold Start Problem too?

Comment: You may be thinking about cold starts prior to some enhancements made to reduce their impact . See https://aws.amazon.com/blogs/compute/new-for-aws-lambda-predictable-start-up-times-with-provisioned-concurrency/

Answer (score 6, accepted):

AWS [will reuse Lambda containers](https://aws.amazon.com/blogs/compute/container-reuse-in-lambda/) if possible. So not every request requires a new container to be provisioned. AWS does have to [provision a separate Lambda container instance](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/lambda/latest/dg/runtimes-context.html) for each concurrent request. So if there are 1000 requests being processed simultaneously, there will need to be 1000 total Lambda container instances provisioned.